# irrationality of $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{\frac{1}{m}}$

Tags: irrational-numbers

For arbitrary $n \geq 2$ and $m \geq 2$,
is
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}  k^{\frac{1}{m}}$$
an irrational number?

Comment: Please show your progress on the problem.

Comment: Any reason to believe we'd know? I mean there's that whole "$\pi+e$" lack of elementary knowledge thing going on with these problems...